# I am trying to terminate while() loop which is using fgets() function

Tags: c, string, loops

```
char src[5][100];
size_t counter = 0 ;  // counter for src as it is two dimensional            
printf("Enter the string : ");
while( counter < 5 && (fgets(src[counter],100,stdin) != NULL) && src[counter][0] != '\0' ) {
    counter++; 
}
```

I am trying to terminate this loop, one way is to take some kind of fixed input like quit or something, I don't want to use that.
Another way is to press ctrl + D to tell EOF , I don't want to do that too.

Comment: Please let me know the proper solution of this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: How should we know what you want to do? All you've said is what you don't want to do. It is hard to give suggestions given an anti-specification.

Comment: I want to terminate this loop @JohnColeman

Comment: Throwing your computer out the window will terminate the loop. You've given absolutely no indications of the conditions under which you want to terminate the loop.

Comment: That will certainly terminate my computer and my loop Sir, I just want to terminate this loop , the loop is keep going , let say it has to run for count < 5 , and If I don't want to input 5 lines , I want to terminate that loop before that somewhere after 2 lines, I guess this is what you want me to indicate you @JohnColeman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `fgets` reads a line, it *includes* the terminating end line character `\n`. If a user just presses `enter`, fgets will return the string `"\n"` rather than the empty string. Try replacing the condition

```
src[counter][0] != '\0'
```

by

```
src[counter][0] != '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

`break;` is what you are looking for, it can break a loop at any point

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx

Also `continue` is for skipping one loop cycle

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3dc2z3.aspx

Comment: I am pretty sure that break would not work in there

Comment: @DeveshPratap why not?

Comment: @DeveshPratap could it be you want to terminate the loop when you are inside the `fgets` function?

Comment: you can put break in any loop (for, while, do while) and it will automatically finish it) you can also use return to exit from the entire function

Comment: the loop is keep going , let say it has to run for count < 5 , and If I don't want to input 5 lines , I want to terminate that loop before that somewhere after 2 lines

Comment: @DeveshPratap read the link, break is exactly that, whatever is your case for breaking, calling break exits the loop without any condition. please try before stating it won't work

Answer (score 1):

As @Vladp said you either use break inside the while loop, or you have a control variable that you add to the continue condition. the only way to decide or not continuing the loop is with a if statement, and in that if you can check, for example, number of repetitions, elapsed time, or as you said, input get from fgets().

Comment: the loop is keep going , let say it has to run for count < 5 , and If I don't want to input 5 lines , I want to terminate that loop before that somewhere after 2 lines

Comment: so you want to terminate the fgets blocking instruction.

Comment: as far as I know there is no such thing, so your best option is run this code in a diferrent thread

Comment: Do these desires ("I want to termiinate that loop") come on you randomly, or is there some *condition* that determines if the loop needs to terminate? If the latter -- either change the control expression governing the while loop so that this condition automatically ends the loop, or test the condition in the body of the loop and then break out. Two people have made these suggestions, but you seem unhappy with them.

Comment: I have tried exit(),break, but while using fgets(), this statement , src[counter] != '\0', it is not working, I know we use break for terminate the loop, let suppose my need is to take 100 line of input or may be more,I tried  {if(src[counter] == '\0') break;} its not working, let say I've some thing like this #define STOP 'Q' and in my while loop I write something like this while(...... && str[counter] != STOP), that will certainly work, I want to do this with '\n' character, if I press 2 enters, more precisely, two '\n' characters together, and boom! terminate @JohnColeman

Comment: I have tried exit(),break, but while using fgets(), this statement , src[counter] != '\0', it is not working, I know we use break for terminate the loop, let suppose my need is to take 100 line of input or may be more,I tried  {if(src[counter] == '\0') break;} its not working, let say I've some thing like this #define STOP 'Q' and in my while loop I write something like this while(...... && str[counter] != STOP), that will certainly work, I want to do this with '\n' character, if I press 2 enters, more precisely, two '\n' characters together, and boom! terminate @AsierSánchezRodríguez

Comment: @DeveshPratap "_if I press 2 enters, more precisely, two '\n' characters together, and boom!_" That's all we needed to know: On what basis the loop should be terminated. How do you expect us to know that without you telling us??

Comment: scr[counter][0] != '\0'.. I guess this means the same "if I press 2 enters, more precisely, two '\n' characters together, and boom!  ", my mistake if that doesn't mean the same, but could you give me some solution for this problem ? @CoolGuy

Comment: @DeveshPratap See John's answer. Doesn't that do what you expect?

Comment: you mean I need to use break statement ?@CoolGuy

Comment: Its working.. thanks @CoolGuy